# Booting linux from usb using EFI

Tags: ubuntu, boot, linux-mint, live-usb, refit

I need to use a USB drive as an installation media for my Mint and Ubuntu.
For that I have unetbootin to make the usb bootable.

But my PC only supports EFI boot (while adding the boot device, I need to provide an `.efi` file path etc).

My question is how can I make my Linux distribution by copying some files (`.efi` file)?

I have heard of a boot loader called `elilo`, but don't know how to use. And I tried [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html), [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) etc., they are booting from usb,
but I don't know how to configure it to boot the Linux distribution in my usb drive.

Comment: What type of PC?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to install an EFI bootloader to the USB drive; [elilo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/elilo/) is what I've used before, but you could potentially use [GRUB2](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/). The [Ubuntu amd64 elilo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/elilo) package installs the 64bit binary to `/usr/lib/elilo/elilo.efi` and the 32bit binary to `/usr/lib32/elilo/elilo.efi`.

EFI firmware will search removable media for a FAT32 filesystem containing the file `/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi` (for both 32bit and 64bit systems). Make sure that you're using a FAT32 filesystem on the USB drive, and copy `elilo.efi` to that path.

Some EFI systems may also need a startup script, in which case put the following in `/EFI/BOOT/startup.nsh`:

```
BOOTX64
```

You then probably want to create a config file for elilo to specify how to boot the kernel. Create `/EFI/BOOT/elilo.conf` and configure it as appropriate for the distro you want to boot. My configuration to boot [RIPLinux](http://www.tux.org/pub/people/kent-robotti/looplinux/rip/) looks like this:

```
image=/riplinux/kernel64
        label=rip64
        initrd=/riplinux/rootfs.cgz
        append="root=/dev/ram0 rw"
```

And that should be it. There is no "install to MBR" type operation in EFI.

By the way, Rod Smith's [Managing EFI Boot Loaders for Linux](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/index.html) site is very useful for understanding how EFI works.

Comment: Thanks, i tried with new Mint 13 version where i found the efi boot loader(grub 2) in it by defualt. I managed to start the boot loader, but i could not start the linux from it. After choosing "install linux mint" the whole screen goes black and unresponsive. I could not figure out what's happening. I will try your method.

Comment: @QuickSilver That sounds like a problem with Linux, not the bootloader then. You may need to play with the video options to the kernel.

Comment: Update: I could boot using a DVD as media.